# why we convert normal to stndard normal?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

when we have pdf of any distribution in order to find probability in a specific range of that random variable, we integrate that function with respect to that variable like "x" , but in case of normal why we convert normal random variable into standard normal variable(z)?

Answer (score 1):

Predominantly because, historically, the integration of the PDF of a normal variable was almost always performed via table lookup of values for the normal CDF. It was far easier to generate one table for $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and convert the specific problem to use that same table. Nowadays it isn't as big of deal due to the ease of numerical integration.

I don't have a source on this and it is entirely possible that there is an alternate reason. If someone knows, please correct me.

Comment: This is a good reason. Also, some analysis is made more readable by referring to a standard normal distribution.  If a decision is arbitrary, might as well make a choice that's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggests it is to standardize a normal to the standard normal.

In terms of integration, they are equivalent (by a change of variable):

Normal probability density function with $N(\mu,\sigma)$: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$

$P(a\le X\le b)=\int_a^b f(x)dx.$

Standard normal probability density function with $N(1,0)$: $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}$

$P(c\le Z\le d)=\int_c^d f(z)dz.$

Note: If it is made the change of variable $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, the first integral results in the second.